# What's the best semantic term for that which is below the header?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

```
<body class="App">
  <header />
  <div class="below-header">
    <nav>
    <article>
    <footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

What's the best semantic html tag or class name to use in place of `div.below-header`? Options include `<section>` or `<div class="App-body">`, etc.

According to [Usage Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main), `<main>` doesn't fit:

> Content that is repeated across a set of documents or document sections such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms should not be included unless the search form is the main function of the page.

Comment: Weird, I've always used `main`. Why doesn't it fit? I couldn't see anything noteworthy in the link you shared.

Comment: I think `main` is OK. Or you can also use `section`, it doesn't look like evil

Comment: Not `main` because it has repeated content like nav and footer inside. Not `section` because it's not a standalone section of functionality—eg it has a nav inside. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section "Each <section> should be identified, typically by including a heading (<h1>-<h6> element) as a child of the <section> element." and "Do not use the <section> element as a generic container; this is what <div> is for, especially when the sectioning is only for styling purposes. A rule of thumb is that a section should logically appear in the outline of a document."

Comment: You need this `div` only for layout purposes, right? Or what is the reason for including `nav`, `article` and `footer`? (i.e., why do you exclude the `header` but include the `footer`?)

Comment: Yes, the element is only needed for layout